# Documentation: Are examples required to be able to compile?

Tags: discussion, documentation

**Short version**

When a language includes compilation, should the examples in Documentation be able to compile?

(Except - of course - examples with the purpose of showing illegal code.)

**Background**

I was reading a topic in Documentation and came across an example containing code that was unable to compile. So I decided to do an edit. The edit was rather small and didn't change the overall intend of the topic. It only fixed the errors that prevented successful compilation.

My edit was rejected (after being accepted by 3 and rejected by 3). The user profiles of the 3 rejecting users, don't show much/any activity in the specific language.

**What to do?**

My first reaction was that I should find out how I could dispute their decision and send the proposed edit for a second review.

But then I got in doubt: Maybe it is perfectly fine that examples can't compile. Maybe it is more important that an example illustrates a topic correct and less important that the code can compile.

So I see two options

a) Send the proposed edit for a second review (somehow)

b) Forget about it (as it isn't a quality improvement to make the code able to compile)

To make up my mind I like to know whether it is intended that Documentation examples shall be able to compile?

Comment: For completeness: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/118808?filter-tags=c

Comment: I would say that yes, example code on a documentation site must be error-free. Otherwise, what's the point? On the other hand, it shouldn't be necessary in the general case to include boilerplate code (like `public static class Program { public static void Main() { … } }`) or complete instructions on how to set up the build process; that would only distract from what the example is trying to show.

Comment: (Note in my above comment that examples without all necessary boilerplate code will *not* compile without a small amount of work. So, to summarize: Example code must compile in the sense that it should not contain any errors; but it is not required to compile because it might not be a complete program.)

Comment: Well, one might want to show examples of things which do not compile so as to demonstrate common issues people face dealing with compiler error messages... This seems like a proposal to fix something which is tangential to the actual issue: people who don't know squat about a language are approving/rejecting changes to documentation.

Comment: In this case I think you were exactly right in making it compileable.  We do not need the boiler plate and the includes but having multiple variables with the same name not only makes it not compile but also less clear.

Comment: The person asking the code should be able to compile it but I don't think a complete example is necessary. We can comment out regions and say //insert finding location here because it's not part of question

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If so I guess the author will say something along the line  "here is an example thjat doesn't compile i will explain why", I don't have any objection too that

Answer (score 13):

My point which follow the current comments:

- The code must compile and shouldn't produce any unexpected behaviour at runtime
- Usual boilerplate (main declaration,...) can be skipped